# How to use the pandas.melt() while keeping the NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I`m cleaning a messy data frame where some of the information needed appear in the column names. This information should melt to a single column that would be created.

```
index    name       animal    fruit    veg
--------------------------------------------------
0        cow        animal    NaN      NaN
1        apple      NaN       fruit    NaN
2        carrot     NaN       NaN      veg
3        dog        animal    NaN      NaN
4        horse      animal    NaN      NaN
5        car        NaN       NaN      NaN
6        pear       NaN       fruit    NaN
7        pepper     NaN       NaN      veg
8        cucumber   NaN       NaN      veg
9        house      NaN       NaN      NaN
```

I've tried using the `pandas.melt()` function, however it returns a lot of rows with "wrong" `NaN` values and duplicates.

Some of the rows are supposed to show `NaN`, but only the ones who don't fit into the categories specified in the column names, so I can't use the `pandas.dropna()`.

Also I can't be sure that removing the duplicates wouldn't remove important data.

This is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index', 'name'],
        value_vars=['animal', 'fruit', 'veg'],
        var_name='type')
```

The result I need should look something like this:

```
index    name       type
--------------------------------------------------
0        cow        animal
1        apple      fruit
2        carrot     veg
3        dog        animal
4        horse      animal
5        car        NaN
6        pear       fruit
7        pepper     veg
8        cucumber   veg
9        house      NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do (*assuming the index is not a column , instead an index*) , using [`df.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df['type']=df[df.columns[1:]].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
#alternatively-> df['type']=df.loc[:,['animal','fruit','veg']].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
df_new=df[['name','type']]
print(df_new)

           name    type
index                  
0           cow  animal
1         apple   fruit
2        carrot     veg
3           dog  animal
4         horse  animal
5           car     NaN
6          pear   fruit
7        pepper     veg
8      cucumber     veg
9         house     NaN
```